# immutable to mutable

Tags: java, immutability, mutable

How do I wrap an immutable class in a mutable one?
For example wrapping `Integer` and `String` and create `MutableInteger` and `MutableString`.

It seems that there are various ways available for doing this. I want to do this with less effort on coding side while maintaining readability.

Comment: "Most clean" (aka "best") questions are typically off-topic for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/faq In your case, I expect if you just rephrase ("How do I wrap an immutable class in a mutable one") you'll be fine. Add a concrete example.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please give more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll add details shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a *mutable companion* class that sees the internals of the immutable object and provides public mutator methods. The best way to achieve this is to make the mutable companion a nested class inside the immutable class.

However, don't expect to actually mutate JDK's standard classes like `Integer` or `String`. That is out of the question. You can only write facade classes that replace their internal `String`s or `Integer`s with new intstances upon mutation.